# Check for non trailing or leading NA's in a vector

Tags: r, na

I would like to find if a vector has `NA`s that are non leading or trailing.

For example, `c(NA, NA,1,8,6, NA,NA, 5, 11, 16,15, 18, NA, NA)` should return `TRUE`, and `c(NA, NA,1,8,6, 7,8, 5, 11, 16,15, 18, NA, NA)` should return `FALSE`.

Does anyone know how to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length(rle(is.na(c(NA, x, NA)))$values) > 3`

This adds an `NA` to each end of `x` and then uses run length encoding to detect if there are more than three sections of `NA` and non-`NA`.

Comment: This is so useful, but it is also just pure magic.

Comment: Thanks @diomedesdata for the nudge to add some explanation